# How to know where the script stopped?

Tags: php, debugging, exit

I was wondering if there was a way to know where the script stopped (ie: file + line), which would be useful for debugging or for removing stupid 'exit' calls lost somewhere in the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean - stopped? for what reason? If it's because of some error, there is always a line number already in the error message.

Comment: Knowing the reason is one of the points of knowing where it stopped. I know that errors tells the line number, get serious pls. If the script stopped because of an 'exit()' call with no arguments, it won't say anything.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong (and I'm sorry for not testing it first): <del>You could use [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) in conjunction with [debug_backtrace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).</del>

See here for a duplicate of your question: [Fastest way to determine where PHP script exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216963/fastest-way-to-determine-where-php-script-exits) .

Comment: I thought of that, but have you ever tried that? I only get 1 trace, and is not useful at all. Seems like it is called from outside the call stack

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove exit from the script, try using PHP Code Sniffer PEAR package http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer

Just create a sniffer to find out where all the exits are in the code (you get a report of file and line).

If you want to find out what line a script stopped at, use a debugger and you can get a stack trace to find out the last line a script executed too (Xdebug is easy to use and set up). Any debugger is going to severely hinder performance as it needs to manage more memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what IDE your using (if any), but this would be trivial using xdebug. I personally use it with netbeans and it works great although it is a bit tricky to setup. It will let you walk through your code step by step and show exactly where it is exiting.