# Determine where PHP is exiting using code, not debugger

Tags: php

I cannot figure out where an application is exiting.  I'd rather not bother with a debugger, and adding `declare(ticks=1);` to each file would be a pain (I'm not in the mood for dealing with sed).  A similar question has been asked, but not with these constraints.

How can I figure out where the code is exiting?

### Clarification:

While this question is similar to [Fastest way to determine where PHP script exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216963/fastest-way-to-determine-where-php-script-exits), I'd like to find a solution that works without a debugger.  I know how to do this with a debugger, but I don't always have access to such tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to determine where PHP script exits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216963/fastest-way-to-determine-where-php-script-exits)

Comment: Thanks @jrd1; while that question certainly is relevant, I'm looking for a different sort of solution.  I'll add clarification.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use a debugger?

Comment: @jrd1 I don't always have root access to my clients' servers.  Sometimes they use shared hosting for quick development.  I used Xdebug this time, but in the future, I'd like to have a code-based solution.

Comment: Ah! I see. Makes sense. I'll try to find a better solution, too. And my sincere apologies.

Comment: @jrd1 No problem.  I greatly appreciate your help.  Sorry for not making that subtle different clearer.

Comment: My advice to you is to only ever have one exit point, that solves your problem instantly. Alternatively, you can use `exit($code)` to specify a code the program returns, and check that.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha That would be ideal, but I'm debugging applications that I haven't programmed.  If had I programmed these applications, they wouldn't be exiting without reason when problems occur.

Comment: @Zenexer: In which case, a debugger is probably your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add declare(ticks) to all your files. one entry point would be enough:

```
<?php
function my_tick()
{
    echo 'tick';
}

register_tick_function('my_tick');
declare (ticks=1)
{
    include("lib.php");
    echo "1";
    test();
}
```

and lib.php:

```
<?php

echo "2";

function test(){

  echo "3";

}
```

and as you are looking for a code-based solution i assume your sources do provide single entry point.

Comment: This sounds plausible.  It's slightly different from what I was attempting: I was including the `declare` statement (early), which didn't work.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I usually instrument my code using a variable to log events then decide what to do at the exit point by registering a shutdown function:

```
class flightRecoder {
   var $data;
   var $err;
   function __constructor() {
     $this->data=array();
   }
   function error($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
   {
      if ($this->err<$errno) {
         $this->err=$errno;
      }
      $this->note("ERROR! $errno $errstr", $errfile, $errline);
   }
   function note($note, $infile, $atline) {
      $this->data[]="$note in $infile at $atline";
   }
   function finish() {
       if ($this->errno || rand(1,20)==19) {
           ....
       }
   }
}
$log=new flightRecorder();
register_shutdown_function(array($log, 'finish'));
set_error_handler(array($log, 'error'));
```

In your case it would simply be a matter of ensuring that error_logging was enabled (to catch fatal errors) then injecting a note before any exit statement.